# Connect consecutive words of a list

Tags: python, list, graph, distance

I need to connect consecutive words of a list.

the list is:

```
lis = ['hello', 'world', 'I', 'say', 'hello', 'to', 'you']
```

I just connect words if they are adjacent, trough a graph (I created through a class).
So 'hello' is connected to 'world', 'world' to 'hello' and 'I', 'I' to 'world' and 'say'.

I said this to python, this way.

```
g = Graph()   #A graph is described by a proper class. 

for el in lis:
    for el1 in lis:
        if abs(lis.index(el) - lis.index(el1)) == 1:  #if the distance is 1
           g.addEdge(el, el1)    #this creates connections
```

THIS WORKS but if in the list there are the same words ('hello' and 'hello' in this case), the algorithm connects just the first of the two words (just the first 'hello' in this case).

How do I say to python to do the same thing also with the other words?

Answer (score 1):

You could make your elements tuples `(index, word)`, then `(0, "hello")` is different to `(4, "hello")`:

```
elements = list(enumerate(lis))
```

Note that you can also simplify your adjacency test, e.g. by `zip`ping:

```
for pair in zip(elements, elements[1:]):
```

Where a `pair` is, for example, `(0, 'hello'), (1, 'world')`

Putting that together:

```
elements = list(enumerate(lis))
for pair in zip(elements, elements[1:]):
    g.addEdge(*pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in one pass:

```
prev = None
for word in lis:
    if prev is not None:
        g.addEdge(prev, word)
    prev = word
```

If `None` is a valid word then you can do:

```
_MISSING = object()
prev = _MISSING
```

and

```
if prev is not _MISSING
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, which is that the `Graph` interprets e.g. `addEdge("say", "hello")` as adding a new node `"say"` and connecting it to the *existing node* `"hello"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - true, but as it stands, there is no way for the graph in the code to know :-)  All `"hello"`s look the same in the OP too.